# Differential of a smooth function is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry

I have encountered a concept differential, and I am confused why differential is a smooth function. Let $f \in C^\infty(M)$, where $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $n$.

Differential of $f$ at $p$ is defined as: $df_p: T_pM \rightarrow \mathbb R$; $\quad$
$df_p(X_p) := X_p(f)$, where $X_p \in T_p(M)$.

Hence, $df_p = \sum a_i(p) dx^i|_p$ for some function $a_i$. Dropping $p$, I get: $df(X) = Xf$, and to show that $df$ is a smooth map, it suffices to show that $a_i$ is a smooth mapping defined on $M$. However, how do I show it?

Comment: try working in coordinates

Comment: In local coordinates, $\mathrm{d}f = \sum_i \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \mathrm{d}x^i$. You can show this by evaluating $\mathrm{d}f$ on the basis $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \right)$.